# How to use RTK Query with ErrorBoundary

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Are there some examples of use with `ErrorBoundary`?

This is what i can think of:

```
const { isError: isGetAError, error: getAError } = useGetAQuery()
if (isGetAError) {
  throw getAError
}
const { isError: isGetBError, error: getBError } = useGetBQuery()
if (isGetBError) {
  throw getBError
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would probably be the way to do it, or you create your own `throwingHooks` module with your own way of writing hooks - these are pluggable modules.

Here is the code to the `/query/react` module: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/tree/master/packages/toolkit/src/query/react